# What is the best way to apply a function to a set of routes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to create a filtering system where I can apply a set of sanity checks to a subset of routes on a REST API. What is the most railsy way to create the mapping of routes to functions which need to be called on that route? I am looking to create a one to many mapping where a function can be mapped to more than one route. Currently I am creating a module where I am mapping the routes and checking the request after it comes in. Is there a native rails way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about *best* way but *one* way would be to create a controller with this sanity check and have your controllers inherit from it.

```rb
class SanityController < ApplicationController
  before_action :sanity_check
  
  def sanity_check
    # some world class sanity checks
  end
end

class OtherController < SanityController

end
```

You can also skip certain actions if needed

```rb
class OtherController < SanityController
  skip_before_action :sanity_check, only: :index
end
```